# Proper naming for the case of omit of Relative Pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

In this sentence:

> Our professional designers produce high-quality custom logo designs that exhibit the image (that) our clients want to project.

I've added above (that) to the original sentence to denote the point of my concern.

I had guessed this sentence is the compound of two compartment, which are "Our professional designers produce high-quality custom logo designs that exhibit the image" and "our clients want to project (the image)".

Then I had concluded this merge falls into the case of a relative pronoun.

My question is:

1. Does this omit the relative pronoun?
2. If it does, is there any formal term that describes this grammatical phenomenon?

Comment: Preliminary point: "that" is not a relative pronoun but a subordinator. Relatives without "that" or a _wh_ relative pronoun are called 'bare relatives'. "That" can be freely omitted provided the relativised element is not subject of the relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ What is the main characteristic difference between relative pronoun and subordinator?

Comment: A relative pronoun like "who", "which" etc., is anaphorically linked to an antecedent expression -- it has a meaning which is provided by the antecedent. But subordinators like "that" are not anaphoric, they are meaningless lexemes serving simply to introduce  a clause. I do realise that many people call relative _that_ a relative pronoun, but many grammarians now accept that it behave like a subordinator and hence belongs in that class.

Comment: *That* can be a relative pronoun (The house **that** fell had been built badly), a demonstrative pronoun (**That** house was built badly), or a subordinating conjunction (He determined **that** the house had been built badly). Ignore BillJ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a name for this. A relative clause in which the relative pronoun has been omitted is called a *reduced relative clause*.

Comment: Non-_wh_ relatives without the subordinator "that" are called 'bare' relatives. A reduced relative clause is one where the relativised element is deleted and the finite relative clause is replaced by a non-finite clause, for example,  _Students who live on campus will be disadvantaged_. vs  _Students living on campus will be disadvantaged_.

Comment: Nope. That second example is a participial phrase, not a reduced relative clause.

Comment: Wake up! It's a clause. We stopped calling such expressions 'phrases' over twenty years ago.

Comment: About when you stopped using "whom"? When you decided that "him and I" is always correct? That is certainly a phrase!

Comment: As it happens, I very much dislike the term 'reduced relative clause', since it's an obvious misnomer, and I never use it myself.  In my second example, the noun "students" is modified by the gerund-participle clause _living on campus will be seriously disadvantaged_.

Comment: @BillJ We know you never use it yourself, but many of us find that it's not a misnomer, because we seem not to have the same grammatical presuppositions that you do. What particular speech group do you represent when you say "***We*** stopped calling such expressions 'phrases' over twenty years ago"? Why did you change, and who changed with you?